# Django: how to get list related ForeignKey records?

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-orm

I am using Django v1.11. Here are 2 models:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()

class TaskUser(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, related_name='task_user')
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='+')
```

So, I want to get **list of tasks** and print in one column list of users that are related to this task. How to do that? The problem is tried a lot: `select_related`, `prefetch_related('task_user')` and so on.. but nothing works. In some cases there are no sql error, but it prints `task.User.None`

```
tasks = Task.objects.all()
```

View must be:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>Users</td>
</tr>
{% for task in tasks %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ task.title }}</td>
    <td>
    {% for user in task.users %}
        {{ user.id }}
    {% endfor %}
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a many-to-many field to Task, using the through model you already have:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, through='TaskUser')
```

and use `.all` when iterating:

```
{% for user in task.users.all %}
    {{ user.id }}
{% endfor %}
```

(Note, you should remove the `related_name='+'` from the `TaskUser.user` field.)